# Issue in alias model name in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, model-associations

I have two models `User` and `Dtype`.
In `users` table I have two column named `dtype_id` and `dtype_second` which contains ID's of Dtype. Now I need to get both the columns values through association.

Using `@user.dtype.name` will give me the value of first column (dtype_id).

Now, I also need the value of second column i.e `dtype_second`.

For this I'm trying this:

```
In User Model:
belongs_to :dtype

In Dtype Model:
has_many :users
has_many :dtype_seconds, :foreign_key => 'dtype_second', :class_name => "User"

On view:
<%= @user.dtype_seconds.name %>
```

The issue is that I'm not getting any value or error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your are adding a has many to `dtype`, but you're trying to call the method on a user. So you have to define the `dtype_second` association on the user:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :dtype
  belongs_to :dtype_alternative, :foreign_key => 'dtype_second', :class_name => "Dtype"

  ...
end

<%= @user.dtype_alternative.name %>
```

Answer (score 2):

First. Naming. You should rename `dtype_second` field to `dtype_second_id`

Next. Associations. You need appropriately describe both associations in both models

```
class User
  belongs_to :dtype
  belongs_to :dtype_second, :class_name => 'Dtype'
end

class Dtype
  has_many :users
  has_many :second_users, :class_name => 'User', :foreign_key => 'dtype_second_id'
end
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer I tried @Mischa answer and its working now.